# Fading In A prepended element in jquery

Tags: jquery

I've got some code like this:

```
var newrootcomment = $("<div class='comment'><div class='comment-holder'><div class='comment-body'>"+ data.message + "</div> <abbr class='timestamp' title=''></abbr><div class='aut'>" + data.author + "</div> <a href='#comment_form' class='reply' id=''>Reply</a> </div> </div>");

$('#wholecontainer').prepend(newrootcomment).hide().fadeIn(300);
```

Basically, I'm prepending the code to the #wholecontainer div. however, I want the prepended code and fade it into view.  The above code fades in all the #wholecontainer div.  How can I actually do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
newrootcomment.prependTo($('#wholecontainer')).hide().fadeIn(300);
```